# Probability problems on Loom

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

A loom experiences one yarn breakage approximately every $10$ hours.
A particular style of cloth is being produced that will take $25$ hours
on this loom. If $3$ or more breaks are required to render the product
unsatisfactory, find the probability that the style of cloth is finished
with acceptable quality.

Answer (score 1):

If you model this on a Poisson process, the average number of breaks in a $25$ hour period is $\lambda=2.5$ and the probability of getting exactly $k$ breaks in the period is $$P(k)=\frac  {\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$  The answer is then $$P(0)+P(1)+P(2)\sim .5438$$

Answer (score 0):

If the first breakage occurs in the first $5$ hours, The Product is unsatisfactory. Else, it is good.

The first break can occur in any of the first $10$ hours with equal probability. So, The probability I say is $1\over 2$.